# How to strikethrough multiple lined text using Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I plan to use the [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) Slack API to fetch a Slack message, and then [chat.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update) to update the message. To be specific, I want to strikethrough the entire message.

Usually adding tilde symbols around the text (i.e. ~text~) works. But my message is not a one-worded text, and rather contains many lines of text.

How do I strikethrough the entire message using Slack API? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude line breaks in the text data. The following should work for you.

```
"~aaa~ \n\n~bbb~\n\n~ccc~"
```